# Google Play Update App Resources

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, updates

I'm just wondering if it's possible to upload an update to an app on the Google Play store in which only a particular resource file is updated so the users only have to download a few KB to update?
I've looked everywhere and can't find any answers to this question.

I ask this because it's obvious with many apps, ie. games, on GPlay that they don't download an entire new game and delete the old one but rather only update particular files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google currently does not support these kind of patches. With the introduction of Firebase, you can [modify remotely properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/android) without uploading a new APK, but this would not achieve what you want.

There are other solutions like [Tinker](https://github.com/Tencent/tinker) which provide a hot-fix solution without uploading a new APK, and satisfies what you want. Although I haven't fully tested it, it has a very good reputation. On the other hand, it has some known issues you should read before in their [github site](https://github.com/Tencent/tinker).

In their app hotfix sample, they update a language resource value as you can see below:
https://github.com/Tencent/tinker/blob/master/tinker-sample-android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml